# Position dropdown menu popup inline with row while right click on row

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Hi i am having below code to get table data while importing of csv file now we are developing functionality while right click on row one menu popup will open and we want to edit row or add new row as attached snapshot.

html file

```
<form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate ng-submit="vm.save()">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"
                ng-click="vm.clear()">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myTaskPlanLabel" data-translate="taskManagementApp.taskPlan.home.importLabel">Create or edit a Task Plan</h4>
        <p> Download a sample CSV file from <a href="https://ge.box.com/s/wfeh0q0xfh2e4qii8h78rnnywhub9ai2" target="_blank">here</a> </p>
        <p> Note: The dates in the CSV file should strictly be in the dd/mm/yyyy format. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>
        <div class="form-group" ng-hide="TaskPlanImportController.results">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="importfile" name="importfile"
                    csv-reader complete="vm.validateResults(importeddata)"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="jh-table table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!-- matamagu
                    <th><span data-translate="global.field.id">ID</span></th>
                    -->
                    <th class="col-sno">S.no</th>
                    <th><span data-translate="taskManagementApp.taskPlan.machine">Machine</span></th>
                    <th><span data-translate="taskManagementApp.taskPlan.project">Project</span></th>
                    <th><span data-translate="taskManagementApp.taskPlan.projectComponent">Project Component</span></th>
                    <th><span data-translate="taskManagementApp.taskPlan.setup">Setup</span></th>
                    <!--
                    <th><span data-translate="taskManagementApp.taskPlan.taskDetails">Task Details</span></th>
                    -->
                    <th><span data-translate="taskManagementApp.taskPlan.plannedStartDateCurrent">Current Start Date</span></th>
                    <th><span data-translate="taskManagementApp.taskPlan.plannedStartDateNew">New Start Date</span></th>
                    <th><span data-translate="taskManagementApp.taskPlan.taskStatus">Task Status</span></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="taskPlanItem in vm.importeddata"
                                ng-right-click="openContextMenu($event, $index)"
                                ng-click="rtcl($event, $index)">

                    <td class="col-sno">
                        <span>{{$index+1}}</span>
                    </td>

                    <!-- matamagu
                    <td><a ui-sref="task-plan-detail({id:taskPlan.id})">{{taskPlan.id}}</a></td>
                    -->
                    <td>
                        <span>
                          <input type="text" class="editable-cell" ng-model="taskPlanItem.Machine" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                          <input type="text" class="editable-cell" ng-model="taskPlanItem.Project" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                          <input type="text" class="editable-cell" ng-model="taskPlanItem.Component" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                          <input type="text" class="editable-cell" ng-model="taskPlanItem.Setup" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <!-- matamagu
                    <td>
                        {{taskPlanItem.Task_Name}}
                    </td>
                    -->
                    <td>
                        <span>
                          <input type="text" class="editable-cell" ng-model="taskPlanItem.Current_Start_Date" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                          <input type="text" class="editable-cell" ng-model="taskPlanItem.New_Start_Date" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                          <input type="text" class="editable-cell" ng-model="taskPlanItem.Task_Status" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
        <div class="context-menu" ng-show="isContextMenuVisible" ng-style="contextMenuStyle">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a tabindex="-1" ng-click="addRow()">New Row</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a tabindex="-1" ng-click="removeRow()">Remove Row</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="vm.addnewrow()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;<span data-translate="entity.action.addrow">Add Row</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="vm.clear()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>&nbsp;<span data-translate="entity.action.cancel">Cancel</span>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="editForm.$invalid || vm.isSaving" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>&nbsp;<span data-translate="entity.action.save">Save</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

css file

```
 .context-menu {
      position: absolute;
    }
    .context-menu .dropdown-menu {
      display:block;
      position:sticky;
    }
```

[image]

JS code

```
$scope.isContextMenuVisible = false;
        $scope.contextmenuRowIndex = -1;
        $scope.openContextMenu = function($event, $index){
          $event.preventDefault();
          console.log($event.button);

          if($event.button === 0){
            $scope.isContextMenuVisible = false;
            return;
          }

          $scope.contextmenuRowIndex = $index;
          $scope.contextMenuStyle = {
            top: $event.clientY + 'px',
            left: $event.clientX + 'px'
          };
          $scope.isContextMenuVisible = true;
        };
        $scope.addRow = function(){
          var index = $scope.contextmenuRowIndex;
          vm.importeddata.splice(index, 0, {});
          $scope.isContextMenuVisible = false;
        };
        $scope.removeRow = function(){
          var index = $scope.contextmenuRowIndex;
          vm.importeddata.splice(index, 1);
          $scope.isContextMenuVisible = false;
        };
```

Now  my problem is while right click on row that dropdown popup is not coming on correct position some times its coming up so when ever we have much data and popup is coming  on top then we need to scroll to see that popup . i tried to use position:fixed but it didn't work as position i can get fix but from js code top and left is coming dynamically in context-menu class.

which is something i think we are calculating wrong top and left value that's why we are not getting popup where we right click to mouse. we are getting x and y position value even we are setting but still we are getting our menu popup not inline with row and this is causing problem whenever we are scrolling table data.

Can some one please help me out to resolve this  issue .

Comment: Why `position:sticky`? I don’t think that makes any sense at all in this situation. What is `openContextMenu`, is that some default angular function, or something you written yourself? If the latter, what does it do exactly?

Comment: i tried to give position:fixed also but it didn't work for me and openContextMenu is function which execute to get above screen (popup) to show table data which we are seeing on above screen .

Comment: added JavaScript code how we are calculating top and left dynamically